# Is it illegal to publish an exploit against a known vulnerability in US?

Tags: exploit, legal, vulnerability

Is it illegal to publish an exploit against a known vulnerability in US? The exploit could be published in one's blog or places like exploit-DB. It seems that in countries like Germany and France such activities are not allowed.

Comment: Before or after responsible disclosure to the vendor?

Comment: @schroeder After. Assuming that the vulnerability is even included in CVE.

Comment: @schroeder Is "responsible disclosure" a well defined concept?

Comment: @curiousguy Google and Wiki have a definition of it, so, yes? It's a defined concept but the specifics are not codified, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @schroeder "_It's a defined concept_" But can you prove to a judge that you did a "responsible disclosure"? Can the other party disprove that?

Comment: @curiousguy - I think the point is if the legal community recognizes "responsible disclosure". Its probably like "non-repudiation" flag added to X509 certificates. *Non-repudiation* has no meaning in the legal community (unlike repudiation, which does have meaning). *Responsible disclosure* is something the computer geeks thought up and added to an RFC. It probably has no legal usefulness.

Comment: That's a good question - is it legal to publish. I have not seen the question answered (yet). I know its legal in the US to perform Security Testing and Evaluation (ST&E), Reverse Engineering (RE), Encryption Research, and Protection of Personally Identifiable Information. You can do it even *without* a company's consent. See Jon Callas' comments at [US rules jailbreaking tablets is illegal](https://lists.apple.com/archives/fed-talk/2012/Oct/msg00134.html). He (and others CompSci heavyweights) provided input on the legislation. And its DMCA - PUBLIC LAW 105–304 (exemptions in Section 1201).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consult a lawyer for legal questions.  Answers here won't help you if you get into trouble.

That being said, obviously there are a lot of researchers in the US publishing proof-of-concept code, and even the code that goes into tools like the metasploit framework.  Also, there are some pages you can find from sources like the EFF's [Coders' Rights Project](https://www.eff.org/issues/coders/vulnerability-reporting-faq).

Answer (score 2):

Unless being explicitly asked to discover vulnerabilities in a specific system (e.g analyzing system vulnerability for a specific company), disclosing **detailed** information about a vulnerability and exploit methods which can then be used by and adversary to attack that specific system will allow the owning company to file a lawsuit against you. However, unless they file for a lawsuit, claiming you have put the company at some kind of risk, simply disclosing information about vulnerabilities and providing an exploit will not get you into trouble. Keep in mind that exploits are sometimes meant to **prove** that a specific vulnerability is dangerous and should be addressed.

As for the lawsuit, the charges you face will vary depending on the damage, but that doesn't mean for certain that you will face legal punishment. It can be argued that (as a consumer) disclosing vulnerabilities (or proof that the vulnerabilities are dangerous e.g exploits) about a product you consume is your legal right. As you have paid for the product/service, and you expect the highest quality of service, and certain vulnerabilities in that product can harm you and other customers.

However, if your exploit is used for any illegal activity (e.g causing the company financial damage) you will be legally responsible **regardless** of the company filing a lawsuit against you or not.

Comment: In short, this comes down to the line between civil liability and criminal liability.

Comment: That's one way of looking at it but for the most part there are clear cut laws about what is legal and what is not

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. What about open source software?

Comment: Could you describe the applicable doctrine or law?

Comment: Dropping 0-days and selling companies short to profit from the drop in stock price is apparently legal from the financial side (according to the Washington Legal Foundation). See [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcoilJkd0Ok) about Weev's [TRO LLC](http://www.newrepublic.com/article/117477/andrew-weev-auernheimers-tro-llc-could-send-him-back-prison) (a company he is trying to set up to do it).

Comment: Open source software is used but not owned by a particular company and therefore cannot be used in a legal dispute. Even if it is a software system that is being used (but not owned) by the damaged company, they cannot take legal action against you. I was explicitly talking about computer systems owned by the company

Comment: @AbbasJavanJafari OSS (open source software) is not without copyright and copyright owners.

Comment: @curiousguy Of course! I was comparing open source projects with software systems tailored (by the developer) for specific companies. One who uses OSS cannot claim that he owns the specific software or software system. That doesn't mean the software itself is without copyright :)